# How to trigger a click event programmatically?

Tags: javascript, events, oracle-adf

I'm trying to click panel splitter collaplse/expand button with javascript / jquery, to no avail.

Here is an example of the splitters: http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/components/index.jspx;jsessionid=GTYNMf7Mq2JD6L4v38yCdTh2HLplhJYLTGc1J1TjZFwmpZjcqh1n!-294683649?_afrLoop=28596129526428344&_afrWindowMode=0&_afrWindowId=null#%2Fcomponents%2FpanelSplitter.jspx%40

As you can see, when you click the small buttons with arrows, the regions collapse. If I try to get element and click it, nothing happens.

```
$("dmoTpl:innerVerticalSplitter::i").onclick()
```

If I load jquery script and trigger click, also nothing happens. I'm a bit confused how this all works and why script clicks are ignored. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use JQuery, but here is an example that works using vanilla javascript and the `<af:clientListener/>` tag.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <af:resource type="javascript">
    function toggleSplitter(evt) {
        comp = evt.getSource().findComponent('ps1');
        if (comp) {
            comp.setProperty("collapsed", !comp.getProperty("collapsed"));
        }
        else {
            alert('not found');
        }
    }
  </af:resource>
  <af:panelStretchLayout id="psl1">
    <f:facet name="center">
      <af:panelSplitter id="ps1">
        <f:facet name="first">
          <af:outputText value="First" id="ot1"/>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="second">
          <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl1">
            <f:facet name="footer"/>
            <af:commandButton text="Toggle" id="cb1" immediate="true">
              <af:clientListener method="toggleSplitter" type="click"/>
            </af:commandButton>
            <af:outputText value="Second" id="ot2"/>
          </af:panelFormLayout>
        </f:facet>
      </af:panelSplitter>
      <!-- id="af_one_column_stretched"   -->
    </f:facet>
  </af:panelStretchLayout>
</jsp:root>
```

before click it is expanded:

[image]

and after click it is collapsed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is click() not onclick() with jQuery, but when I checked your code $ is not jQuery. Are you sure this page has jQuery on it?

Comment: The page from the link does not use jquery, no. I'm working on an ADF project and my page can use it, but I don't think there's any public demo which uses both.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to create a click event, if you know the event handler it is typically better to directly call that method directly.  Here's an example in jQuery.

Setup of the event handler

```
var clickEventHandler = function(event) {
  ...
};

$('#some-button').click(clickEventHandler);
```

Calling it programmatically later

```
clickEventHandler();
```

Comment: The point is, I'd just like to emulate user click from the javascript / jquery.


The "dmoTpl:innerVerticalSplitter::i" is an anchor which seem to do it, but I don't really understand how exactly it works. Calling click from jquery on it does nothing.

This is the button's html:


<a id="dmoTpl:innerVerticalSplitter::i" class="xn6" onclick="return false" href="#" title="Bereich ausblenden"><img border="0" alt="Bereich ausblenden" title="Bereich ausblenden" src="/adf-richclient-demo/afr/fusion/splitterhc.png"></a>

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to trigger an event on an element. Consider the below code which triggers various events.

```
$('#myElement').trigger('click');
$('#myElement').trigger('mousedown');
$('#myElement').trigger('touchstart');
```

Answer (score 0):

For programmatically expand/collapse af:panelBox, create event and queue it programmatically as shown below.

To collapse ***af:panelBox***

```
DisclosureEvent discEvent = new DisclosureEvent(panelBoxCompObj, false);
discEvent.queue();
```

To expand ***af:panelBox***

```
DisclosureEvent discEvent = new DisclosureEvent(panelBoxCompObj, true);
discEvent.queue();
```